# How to set up socket to connect to other devices

Tags: java, networking

I am trying to learn Java network programming to send files and strings. However, I only know how to do this on the localhost, what would I need to change to allow communication with other devices on the same network or another network? Here's my code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Client {
    private int fileSize;
    private String FileName;
    public void getFileInformation (File newFile) {
        fileSize = (int) newFile.length();
        FileName = newFile.getName();
    }
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        try {
            Client newClient = new Client ();
            Socket newSocket = new Socket("localhost",3333);
            DataInputStream newDataInput = new DataInputStream(newSocket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream newDataOutput = new DataOutputStream(newSocket.getOutputStream());  
            BufferedReader newReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("Enter path of file: ");
            File newFile = new File(newReader.readLine());
            newClient.getFileInformation(newFile);
            newDataOutput.writeInt(newClient.fileSize);
            newDataOutput.writeUTF(newClient.FileName);
            byte [] fileData = Files.readAllBytes(newFile.toPath());
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fileData));
            newDataOutput.write(fileData);
            newSocket.close();
            newDataInput.close();
            newDataOutput.flush();
            newDataOutput.close();
            newReader.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
        }
    }
}

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.DataInputStream;
    import java.io.DataOutputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    public class Server {
        private int fileSize;
        private String FileName;
        public static void main (String [] args) {
            try {
                Server newServer = new Server();
                ServerSocket newServerSocket = new ServerSocket(3333);  
                Socket newSocket = newServerSocket.accept();  
                DataInputStream newDataInput = new DataInputStream(newSocket.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream newDataOutput = new DataOutputStream(newSocket.getOutputStream());  
                BufferedReader newReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                newServer.fileSize = newDataInput.readInt();
                System.out.println(newServer.fileSize);
                newServer.FileName = newDataInput.readUTF();
                System.out.println(newServer.FileName);
                byte [] fileData = new byte [newServer.fileSize];
                newDataInput.readFully(fileData);
                FileOutputStream newOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(newServer.FileName);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fileData));
                newOutputStream.write(fileData);
                newOutputStream.close();
                newSocket.close();
                newDataInput.close();
                newDataOutput.flush();
                newDataOutput.close();
                newReader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried changing localhost to what Java prints when I use InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(); but that hasn't worked. The client keeps printing "Error: java.net.ConnectionException: Connect refused"

Comment: you need to change localhost to the name of the server (String value) or the ip using [InetAddress](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/Socket.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.net.InetAddress,int) also make sure to allow that port 3333 you using on your firewall of your operating system

Comment: You'll also want to take a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: In general terms, I was able to get your code to work - I would assume that the `Server` isn't running when you run the client